# Android json parser crashing

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying get json data from url.I am following this tutorial:http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html

I am trying get json from this url:http://api.learn2crack.com/android/json/

But my app is crashing,when I look the logcat error is:

```
E/JSON Parser(1936): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 13 of {n"user": [n{n"id": "001",n"name": "Raj Amal",n"email": "raj.amalw@gmail.com"n}n]n}n
```

What is this ? How can I resolve it ?

Comment: are you sure its a valid json?

Comment: No.But this url used in tutorial.

Comment: `{ "user": [ { "id": "001", "name": "Raj Amal", "email": "raj.amalw@gmail.com" } ] }` is valid json where does the `n's` come from. I don't see that in the url

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes,is there any problem with encoding ? So do I can't see  any problem with json.

Comment: its simple. make a http get request and get the json first. then parse the json. i don't know what encoding you are talkng about

Comment: Just remove those "n" from your index.php

Comment: @Than There is no "n" in the link you can check here : http://api.learn2crack.com/android/json/

Comment: Yes i know, but JSON in link is valid and somehow your JSON is not. Find out where does the `n's` come from to fix your problem. Maybe something with unix/win/mac EOL?

Comment: @Than I found the solution,check the source code of json link,you'll see the "n"s,I uploaded raw json to another server my problem is fixed.Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file JSONParser.java remove `+ "n"` in following line `sb.append(line + "n");`. If you see your logcat, you can see that the JSON is not valid.

Or if you want to keep it, change it to `"\n"`.